# Possible to change Eclipse hotkey Ctrl-F11 from "run" to "terminate previous apps and run"?

Tags: java, eclipse

I commonly launch applications from Eclipse using either Run or Debug hotkeys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd>). Then, after some combination of using the application, the debug perspective, and/or the Java perspective, I end up editing code in the Java perspective and would like to launch the app again. A few iterations later, I realize all the previously launched applications are all still running.

I do know how to change key bindings under menu *Window* → *Preferences* → *General* → *Keys*, but I'm hoping for a way to wire one hotkey to "launch this application, but first terminate any running instances of it (ideally in either run or debug mode).

Partial solutions are also welcomed!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With version >= 4.6

> Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching

When the `Terminate and Relaunch ...` checkbox is checked, it should behave as you want.

Comment: Beautiful Oleg!!  Thanks a million!  Works like a charm!

Comment: @user2802450: ... please accept the answer since it worked well for your needs.